# Circle group not a simple group

Tags: differential-geometry, category-theory, lie-groups

In the theory of Lie groups, a simple Lie group is defined as a connected non-abelian Lie group $G$ which does not have nontrivial connected normal subgroups. Only the non-abelian condition excludes the circle group $\mathbb{T}$ from the list of simple groups.

In categorical terms, a simple object is defined as an object which has exactly two quotient objects: the $0$ object and itself. Hence in the category of Lie groups this gives the definition of simple Lie group above **except for** the non-abelian condition. Is there a way to arrive to this definition from the categorical definition? Restricting to the category of non-abelian Lie groups does not seem like a suitable idea since one would ultimately want to talk about the circle or torus groups in one way or another.

In any case, why should one exclude the circle group from the definition?

Comment: I don't think the categorical definition applies, since simple Lie groups may have non-trivial normal subgroups that are not connected. E.g., $SO(n)$ is a quotient of $\mathrm{Spin}(n)$ by a two-element normal subgroup. (P.S., I thing you've forgotten the word "simple" in line 1 of your question.)

Comment: Did you leave out the word "simple" in your first sentence?

Comment: @LeeMosher, you're right, just changed it.